# what make array variable changes its value even if it was assigned by val not reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference

```
$a = array();
$var=array();
$a = array_fill(1, 3, '1');

test($a,$var);

$b = $a;

echo print_r($b).NL;

$a[2]='3';
echo print_r($b).NL;

function test(&$a,&$var){
    foreach($a as $i =>$v)
    {
       $var[$i]= &$a[$i];
    }

Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 ) 1
Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 3 [3] => 1 ) 1
```

outputs 3 in array $b even it is copy by val. It looks like somehow `$var[$i]= &$a[$i];` is making this behavior but as you can see address is assigned to $var not $b.

Comment: By reference-assigning the array element, you turn it into a reference and it'll behave like a reference henceforth. I hope the duplicate explains that adequately.

Comment: at the time of executing assignment statement `$b = $a;`  
isn't variable $b got its own space and copying value from $a?

In other issue you mentioned variable $a and $c are referencing the same adress which is what `$c =& a;`   
does.

But in my code address is assigned to $var not $b.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: The array elements themselves turn into references, as explained in the duplicate. `var_dump` the array to see it. Making a copy of the array basically makes a copy of the references.